# Dynamic programming for subsequence product sum explanation

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

The question is:

"Given an array of integers and an integer `m`, return the sum of the product of its subsequences of length `m`."

E.g. `a = [2,3,4,5]` and `m = 3` then `product_sum = (2*3*4) + (2*3*5) + (2*4*5) + (3*4*5) #=> 154`

I see people solving this exercice with dynamic programming is the following way:

```py
def product_sum(a, m):
    ss = [1] + [0]*m ;
    for n in a:
        for k in range(m,0,-1):
            ss[k] += n * ss[k-1];
        
    return ss[m]
```

This algorithm works, but i cannot understand what does the `ss` array represent ?

I understand it must be some sub sequence partial computation but i cannot wrap my head around the formulation of the problem that could lead me to get to this algorithm.

What does this array represent during execution ? what's the mathematical formulation of the problem that is solved by this algorithm ?

Comment: At iteration `j` of the outermost loop, `ss[i]` is the sum of the products of the subsequences of length `i`  of the subarray `a[0:j]`